# Prove the constancy of a harmonic function with $\lim_{\vert x\vert\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{\ln\vert x\vert}=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be a harmonic function. Suppose
$$\lim_{\vert x\vert\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{\ln\vert x\vert}=0$$
Prove or disprove that $f $ is a constant.

I cannot come up with any example that $f$ is non-constant, so I tend to believe $f$ is constant. From the expression it looks like it is going to use the Liouville Theorem, but I don’t know how to use the $\ln(x)$ condition ($\ln(x)$ is a harmonic function too, but will this be useful?). Are there any ways of dealing this problem? Moreover, I know a problem that if $f$ is continuous and subharmonic with
$$\lim_{\vert x\vert\rightarrow\infty}\sup\frac{\vert f(x)\vert}{\ln\vert x\vert}\le0$$
we can also conclude that $f$ is constant. Can we extend the solution of the former problem to the latter problem? Thanks!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744687/42969 and the remark at the end of the answer.

Comment: Also answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3195476/42969

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t managed to search it out, what did you search to get this link? @MartinR

Comment: I knew of the first one (which is about subharmonic functions) because I has written it :) – the second one was found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7B%5Cvert%20x%5Cvert%5Crightarrow%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Cvert%20f(x)%5Cvert%7D%7B%5Cln%5Cvert%20x%5Cvert%7D%3D0%24)

Comment: @MartinR The assumption can be weakened. I wonder if my answer is correct.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I think it is correct, and you can even relax it to $\liminf_{r \to \infty} \frac{M(r, f)}{r} < \infty$, similar as in the answer that I linked to above. For *subharmonic* functions it suffices that $\liminf_{r \to \infty} \frac{M(r, f)}{r} =0$, as mentioned in the answer that I linked to above, and $f(z) = \max(0, |z|)$ shows that a finite $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ is not sufficient.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for verification. Indeed $\liminf_{r\to \infty} {M(r,f)\over \ln r}<\infty $ is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

**The assumption can be weakened to**
$$\limsup_{|z|\to \infty}{f(x,y)\over \ln|z|}=:r_0<\infty, \ z=x+iy\qquad(*)$$
Fix $r>r_0.$ By $(*)$
we obtain
$$f(x,y)-r\ln|z|< 0,\qquad |z|> R$$
for some $R>0.$

Let $f(x,y)=\Re F(x+iy),$ where $F$ is holomorphic. Then
$G(z)=\exp \,F(z)$ satisfies $$|G(z)|=\exp(f(x,y))\neq 0, \qquad z=x+iy$$
We have
$$ {|G(z)|\over |z|^r}= \exp (f(x,y)-r\ln |z|)<1 ,\qquad |z|>R$$
Thus
$$|G(z)|\le |z|^{r},\qquad |z|>R$$
As $|G(z)|$ is bounded for $|z|\le R$ we obtain
$$|G(z)|\le |z|^{r}+C_r$$ for a constant $C_r>0.$ Therefore the function $G(z)$ is a polynomial. But $G(z)$ does not vanish, hence $G(z)$ is  constant. Therefore $f(x,y)$ is constant.